# Is someone working on a video4linux driver for the camera module?

Tags: driver, raspicam

There are a ton of Linux applications that will interface with a camera with [V4L](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux). It would be totally awesome if there was a V4L driver for the Raspberry Pi Camera module.

Comment: I did read that there will eventually be V4L driver for the camera module. At the moment they are concentrating on getting everything right and finally enabling the 60FPS that was promised too! :) After that they should start work on V4L. It will make video streaming allot easier!

Answer (score 6):

### Edit: [It's here!](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/5580)

Check the release notes for NOOBS v1.3.3:

> Check out the release notes for each distribution for more details.
>   Highlights for Raspbian include:
>
> - New firmware and 3.10 kernel, with numerous functionality    improvements.
> - New hardware-accelerated X driver included and enabled by default.
> - Mathematica and the Wolfram Language installed by default.
> - Updated Scratch image.
> - PyPy 2.2, with incremental garbage collection.
> - **Our new V4L2 camera driver, and an updated v4l-utils package.**

---

There is a topic about that subject on the [Raspberry Pi forums](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=44003&p=350755&hilit=V4L).  To quote one of the mods (jamesh):

> > ucola wrote:
> >     hi all
> >
> > any news about the V4L driver?
> >
> > regards
>
> In progress; it's a big job so I wouldn't be expecting solid anything
>   for a few weeks.

However, the post was made June 06, 2013.

---

There is an [unofficial V4L driver available](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=50639).  It was not funded be the Raspberry Pi Foundation in any way, so I guess he has done this off his own initiative.  I have not tested this driver for myself yet.

Comment: Thats is awesome! But there is some concern to what is happening in the code. This was made by somebody that was not funded or authorised by the foundation. So install this at your own risk.

Comment: Awesome! [Here is a blog articale](http://www.robertcudmore.org/blog/?p=200) I found on how to upgrade and use the latest V4L2 ! :) Happy Days