# What streaming solution for the Picam has the smallest lag?

Tags: camera, streaming-video, raspicam

[This post](http://www.doepiccoding.com/blog/?p=212) shows how to stream using VLC. It works nice and is simple, but it gives me about a second lag. [This post](http://pi.gbaman.info/?p=150) uses GStreamer, and it has 0.3 second lag; I would like less.

Is it possible to use Raspberry Pi graphics chip to speed up the encoding?

Comment: It is not possible yet. 0.3ms lag is very good and you wont get better (as of now) because the lack of V2L. [Maybe this will help](http://pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/live-video-stream-from-raspberry-pi.html)

Comment: @ppumkin I think the OP said the lag was .3 seconds, not milliseconds. Also, do you mean V4L?

Comment: Yea 3ms I was thinking. Video4Linux driver? Or is it called something else. You know. The native driver.

Comment: @ppumkin Ahh, then you would be wrong.  [The V4L2 drivers were included in NOOBS v1.3.3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9777/8631).

Comment: Well then in that case the VLC should just stream the h264 packets as they are (without any more transcodding- set the V4L2 driver to do all the hard work) to the destination. 0.3 seconds is much better than the previous 3seconds solutions. Not sure how you will get faster than 0.3seconds?

Comment: http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=16

Comment: Tx. Will try those drivers soon. I also found a solution using netcat. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I achieved a 200ms lag! The trick: send out less frames from the Pi than you read on the remote side, this makes sure the buffer stays empty.

[Here's a picture](https://plus.google.com/100557917109200166799/posts/ezrK7tW4g8E) I took of the RPi filming a stopwatch. It shows the time difference.

This is the recipe I use. First on the laptop (Mac) do this:

```
nc -l 5001 | mplayer -fps 24 -cache 1024 -
```

then on the RPI start streaming:

```
raspivid -t 999999 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 20 -o - | nc 192.168.178.22 5001
```

Make sure to:

- Install mplayer first. Only the Homebrew method worked for me. The regular download was broken.
- Change the ip number above to the number of your laptop.

Comment: This is a clever trick! I wonder if it works for the new UV4L driver too

Comment: The issue with this solution is that it introduces a lot of stutter from the playback side. I was wondering if you found a solution to that.

Answer (score 9):

With Ubuntu 14.10 and Gstreamer I reach 100 to 116 ms latency with 1280 x 720 @ 60Hz.

Tanks to @Antonvh who puts me on the right way.
I reproduce here the solution for latter reference.

To stream from the Pi :

```
raspivid -t 0 -b 2000000  -fps 60 -w 1280 -h 720 -o - \
  | gst-launch-1.0 -e -vvv fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=5 \ 
  ! udpsink host=10.42.0.1 port=5001
```

To receive it on your computer with gst-0.10 and send it to a virtual v4l2 device (indeed you need [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback)):

```
gst-launch -v udpsrc port=5001 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtph264depay \ 
! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

Then you can open the device `/dev/video1` in any software supporting v4l2 capture.

For a gst-1.0 solution (v4l2loopback doesn't work with gst-1.0), I let you see the [Antonvh blog post](http://antonsmindstorms.blogspot.nl/2014/12/realtime-video-stream-with-raspberry-pi.html).

Answer (score 1):

I use this video recipe: http://archpi.dabase.com/#sending-and-receiving-pi-camera-video-over-the-network

Have you tried https://github.com/thaytan/gst-rpicamsrc ? That should be slightly more streamlined. Tbh, I can't be bothered to try it.

0.3s lag is pretty darn good.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I think I have a less-than-0.3s lag now, I still have to document the solution and measure it precisely. Will post soon. If my measurments prove it's more than 0.3 I wil try the other recipe.

Comment: @Antonvh How's the research/measurements going? Is this answer getting you better results?