# Camera delay reduce

Tags: raspbian, raspicam

I have a project with a raspberry pi zero w, and his camera, and I want to have a video stream and with less delay as possible, and if possible, a stream which can be started with a bash script.
Thanks for answering

Comment: Have a look at motioneyeos https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/wiki

Comment: @SteveRobillard is there an other way with raspbian ?

Answer (score 1):

if you're looking for an open source solution uv4l is not your friend.

Instead have a look at:

[Modern way to stream H.264 from the Raspberry Cam](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/76506/4223)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are lookking for [uv4l](https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/)

This program offer a built-in web server, allowing camera configuration, live stream with low latency and decent fps, low CPU consumption, and some extra features that may, or not, fit your specific needs.

I tried some other solution (ffmpeg, gstreamer), and I think that `uv4l`, being a userspace driver level, is the most performant tool for this.
And it's easy to use :)

Look at the demos to see [implementation samples](https://www.linux-projects.org/demos/)