# I keep running into missing elements with GStreamer

Tags: python-3, gstreamer

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling GStreamer on the Raspberry Pi 3 and I keep finding that I have missing elements.

This is the Pi on Log Level 4 (GStreamer):
[image: Raspberry Pi Log]

This is my laptop, running Debian with the same exact Python script:
[image: Laptop Log]

The script was executed as "python3 rtmp.py". Both are log level 4.

I had uninstalled and reinstalled these packages "python3-gst-1.0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-omx".

When trying to run the command, "gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! videoconvert ! x264enc bitrate=1000 tune=zerolatency ! queue ! flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/STREAM_KEY_HERE' audiotestsrc is-live=true ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,rate=48000 ! voaacenc bitrate=96000 ! audio/mpeg ! aacparse ! audio/mpeg, mpegversion=4 ! mux.", I get the same issue with other elements, such as x264enc.

The error looks like:
"WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "x264enc""

This is with the default log level, 0, and not log level 4 as set by my python script.

How can I install the missing elements and why are they missing on the pi, but easily found on Debian? I get they are different systems, so maybe the package manager either moved them or forgot to put them in. Maybe my system is corrupted? Thanks!

Comment: Debian supports multiple different CPUs.  Raspbian only supports ARM.  Are the missing elements available for the Raspbian variant of ARM in Debian?

Comment: Yes, I know the capfilter exists as it is often used in other gstreamer projects involving the webcam on RPi. I just don't know how to tell which package it is in.

Comment: An example where this is used is at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/26675/64111