# v4l2src zooms when I change resolution

Tags: gstreamer, v4l2

I have a camera module v2, which [supports 1080p@30](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/).

Following [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107577/11810), I am streaming it with gstreamer using:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src do-timestamp=true ! video/x-h264,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! gdppay ! udpsink sync=false host=192.168.0.12 port=5000
```

and receive it on my computer with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink sync=false
```

And this seems fine:

[image: video frame in 640x480]

Now if I change the resolution to 1920x1080 (instead of 640x480), I am expecting to see the same image, but in a better resolution. Instead I get a cropped image (or rather a zoomed image):

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong.  The Raspberry Pi camera uses a cropped portion of the sensor to handle 1080p30 video, so that's why it appears zoomed in.  Alternatively you could do 720p or 960p (1280x960).  720p would give you slightly less crop vertically and zero crop horizontally, and 960p would give you the whole sensor resolution.